# Aggregations for inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent-children mapping in ElasticSearch:

parent: *user*

children: *privileges*

For *privileges* there are a few properties, and one is "*privilegeName*".

The query returns users which have certain privileges, but I would like to return the aggregated *privilegeName*s for each user for the privileges that match the `has_child` query.
I can return all *privileges* with `inner_hits` and process them on the client side, but that may be cumbersome.
Is there a possibility to aggregate the `inner_hits`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the [Children Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html).

For example, let's say I create the following index with the *user* as the parent, and *privilege* as the child:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "privilege": {
      "properties": {
        "privilegeName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "_parent": {
        "type": "user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I add the following users:

```
PUT /my_index/user/1
{
  "name": "sally",
  "age": 32
}

PUT /my_index/user/2
{
  "name":"bob",
  "age": 41
}
```

Then I give each user some privileges. Let's say I give Sally the privilege to 'add','update' and 'delete':

```
POST /my_index/privilege/?parent=1
{
  "privilegeName":"add"
}

POST /my_index/privilege/?parent=1
{
  "privilegeName":"update"
}

POST /my_index/privilege/?parent=1
{
  "privilegeName":"delete"
}
```

But I only give Bob the privilege to 'add' and 'update':

```
POST /my_index/privilege/?parent=2
{
  "privilegeName":"add"
}

POST /my_index/privilege/?parent=2
{
  "privilegeName":"update"
}
```

I can now search for all the users that have the 'add' privilege using the `has_child` query. But, in the `aggs`, I can also show a full list of all the privileges that each of the matching users has:

```
GET /my_index/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "privilege",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "privilegeName": "add"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "to_privs": {
          "children": {
            "type": "privilege"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "user_privs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "privilegeName"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The children aggregation is a good idea. There is an issue though. I would like to paginate the User results. The pagination on Users is not considered for the aggregations. Is there a way to do the aggregations only for the actual results returned by the Query, considering pagination?

Comment: This is an answer from ES folks:
" inner hits performs a further search request for every result. This can already be heavy, adding aggregations would be too much. Rather, run a multi-search with an entry for each hit and calculate the aggregations in there."